# How does Timescale assign chunk ids?

Tags: timescaledb

Timescale allows us to query for chunk sizes in with something like

`SELECT * FROM chunk_relation_size('....');`

I am trying to monitor the chunk sizes so that if any of them reaches a size that is dangerous to be kept in the memory, we can scale the DB as needed.

I am assuming the latest created chunk will be the most read heavy, thus most likely to be kept in memory.

However the `chunk_relation_size` table doesn't expose any timestamps or information on when the chunk was created.

I am wondering if the `chunk_ids` are assigned incrementally or are they completely random? In the former case, I can infer which chunks are latest.

Docs doesn't specify anything. I have skimmed through the [source code](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/blob/master/src/chunk.c) but have been unable to find any clues.

Comment: Every chunk is a table and constraints on the time column are defined for it. So you can use PG catalog to retrieve information about constraints. I can dig into it later.

Comment: I found that in the current implementation chunk id are created incrementally. If your data are inserted in order then the latest chunk id will correspond to chunk with latest data. But if data are inserted in random order, then it might not be satisfied. I guess your data are inserted mainly in order, right?

Comment: @k_rus yes it is inserted in order of even time and you are right.